# Identifying odd plant

Tags: identification

I've been trying to identify this plant for a little bit now, but no success. Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

[image: anthurium]

Comment: Can I ask how long you've had it and how long has it been in that pot?

Comment: What's it's root like?  I mean is it tuberous?

Comment: I've had it several days and has been in that pot for that duration.

Comment: The roots look as follows: https://imgur.com/gallery/jixyq1                                      And it's not very tuberous I don't think

Answer (score 1):

This is an old [anthurium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthurium) that has been grown under low light for a long time.  The long hard stalk is where the old leaves were attached.  The stems should be much shorter but they have stretched out or [etiolated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiolation) under the low light.

I would cut all the leaves off and move to a much higher but diffuse light.  Against a north window or east window.

Repotting is a good idea as well as a dilute fertilizer applied once or twice.

Answer (score 1):

My mother gave us a plant just like this many years ago I took it to florist and landscapers nobody could ever tell me what kind of plant it was It grew to be big and beautiful it never flowered we had it probably 15 years before it just started dying no matter what I did I do look forward to others answers for this question